# What is more efficient in Android layout drawing? android:textColor="#FFFFFF" or android:textColor="@android:color/white"?

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, android-xml

I've always wondered about this question.

When building a XML `Android` layout, we can define a `TextView` text color using the RGB hexadecimal code or a color value from the `color.xml` file.

```
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
```

or

```
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

Is this just a readability issue and does not have any effect at all when drawing the layout or does it make a difference in performance?

Comment: You have to use #fffff or make a color xml and get colors from there.

Comment: there is no difference between the two. It's for readability and, as for every constants, if you it in place of the *magic value*, make a change app-wide takes less changing the constant's value that the *magic value* in every place it is used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are identical. `@android:color/white` is simply a constant defined in the `Color` class that you can reference as opposed to having to call out the specific hex color. The only visible benefit is that it makes your code more readable.

Comment: Do you know about any documentation that can prove that?

Comment: The default system colors are defined in `R.color`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html . As @Dev mentioned, I highly doubt you will ever notice a performance difference between the two.

Comment: Android framework engineer here. The performance difference for resolving resources is negligible. You should prefer @color for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Hardcoded String is good in performance.

```
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
```

and refrence from some class is bit time taking then hardcoded.

```
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

Comment: So, it affects only the build time? Not the runtime?

Comment: I highly doubt that there's a noticeable difference. You can try this yourself.  Create a project a add hundreds of references, try, measure and then change it and compare the results.